# Bloc listiner not listen to changes

Tags: flutter

I am trying to listen to a cubit after changing state but not updating

I have an ads screen

I go edit a car then in my ads screen I am listening to the edit car cubit
if did change

I will update the specific card

but it's not listening why is that!

I tried the same this in the demo app it works

but on this app not
I am working after another developer!!

Comment: Please, provide examples of what your codebase looks like.

Comment: You must extends equatable in your state class, please add your code so i can help your more